# How can I securely push from a GitLab Runner KubernetesExecutor pod to a private container registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## Goal

Build a CI/CD pipeline multiple GitLab repositories with a certain project structure can make use of. For this, a Docker container with Python code is built and subsequently securely pushed to Google Cloud's Container Registry.

## Set up

- KubernetesExecutor is installed on Kubernetes Engine using the [Helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html) as provided by GitLab.
- The base image for the build process (`runners.image` in the `values.yaml`) is a custom one as this helps automatically containerising the provided repository. **The reason this is worth mentioning is that this is from the *same* private repository as where the image should be pushed to.**
- Right now, building the container from the repository runs successfully (see code below).

## Problem

How can I *push* the image to the Container Registry *without* adding a service account key to a Docker image (otherwise, please convince me this isn't bad practice)?

## Code

### .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
services:
  - docker:19.03.1-dind

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY}/pyton-container-test:latest .
    # This line is where I'd need to use `docker login`, I guess.
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY}/python-container-test:latest
```

### values.yaml (Helm)

It's worth mentioning that the following environment variables are set by the GitLab Runner:

```yaml
runners:
  env:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    CONTAINER_REGISTRY: eu.gcr.io/<project_id>
```

## Direction of solution

I think I should be able to mount a secret from the Kubernetes cluster to the GitLab Runner build pod, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Then, I should be able to add the following line into `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```sh
cat mounted_secret.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io
```

Setting up `config.toml` to use a [secret volume](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#secret-volumes) should work. However, with a Helm chart this doesn't seem possible yet.

## Notes

- It *is* possible to set protected environment variables in GitLab CI, but I'd rather not, as they're harder to maintain.
- I've investigated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474255/gitlab-runner-image-with-gcp-credentials) answer, but this says I need to add a key to my Docker image.
- Looked into the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#using-a-private-container-registry) on using a private container registry, but don't seem to get much further with that.
- A similar problem would occur when, for example, it must connect to a database during the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the [default Helm chart](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner) as provided by GitLab. However, **there is a workaround** when you customise theirs.

In `templates/configmap.yaml`, it's possible to edit the `entrypoint`. At the very end, the runner is started as follows:

```
# Start the runner
exec /entrypoint run --user=gitlab-runner \
     --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
```

For this to work, a `config.toml` is generated based upon the provided `values.yaml` (with the right Runner token). This means that *right before* this step, we could edit the `config.toml` to our needs. In my case, I simply added:

```
echo "    [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.secret]]" >> ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo "      name = \"{{ .Values.secretName }}\"" >> ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo "      mount_path = \"/keys\"" >> ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo "      read_only = true" >> ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

Where `${CONFIG_FILE}` is `/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

Finally, you can deploy your GitLab Runner using:

```sh
$ helm install project_name -f values.yaml <path to chart>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` CI/CD variable with auth values from `~/.docker/config.json`. The variable will look like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "northamerica-northeast1-docker.pkg.dev": {
            "auth": "{JSON key here}"
        },
        "us.gcr.io": {
            "auth": "{JSON key here}"
        }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.13 (linux)"
    }
}
```

This way, next time your gitlab runner is trying to pull a docker image from private repo, it will be able to do so.